# How to check if every first element of the tuple is equal to its second element in a dataframe column python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples

I have a dataframe as below:

```
    Data      
(15019, 20218) 
(20218, 20218)  
(20210, 20210)  
(2266, 4905)   
(2429, 2429)
```

I need check if first element of the tuple is equal to its second element for Data column and flag as yes.

desired output:

```
    Data        Flag
(15019, 20218)  No
(20218, 20218)  Yes
(20210, 20210)  Yes
(2266, 4905)    No
(2429, 2429)    Yes
```

I tried this:

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(i[0] == i[1] for i in df['Data']  , 'Yes', 'No')
```

But it gives me

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: The list comprehension inside the `where` needs `[]`.  But I get a different error, and dont see whare `float` comes in.  Are you sure this is the error from this dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['Data'].str[0]==df['Data'].str[1] , 'Yes', 'No')
```